# How to set/change the value of an input field, in Jest, when unittesting a Non-React project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to unit test a form, to make sure my validator displays an error, when there is an invalid value in the input field.

I am using jquery-validation library, and it re-validates on change.
I am using Jest for my tests, and all I found on google are examples of using wrapper for react front end. My front end is JSP, and I am not sure if there is any way to simulate input change.
If user enters an invalid value, I expect to see a new error element in the DOM, and as soon as it changes to a valid text, the element gets removed.

```js
global.$ = global.jQuery = require( 'jquery' );
require('jquery.validate.js');  // The library file
require('form-validators.js');  // My rules and custom validation functions

document.body.innerHTML =
    '<form id="createUser" novalidate="novalidate">' +
    '  <input id="create_email" name="username" required="required" value="">' +
    '</form>';

$('#create_email').text("AN_INVALID_EMAIL");
console.log($('#create_email').text());  // Displays the expected text: AN_INVALID_EMAIL
expect($('#create_email-error').length).toEqual(1);  // This fails
```

I expect the input text change in the DOM, and the change trigger the validation function, so as a result it displays an error